# Odd LiveCD error message that says "??? ???"

Tags: installation, live-cd, livedvd

I have recently taken an interest in Ubuntu and considered putting it on my old computer that just manages to get over the minimum requirements.

However, ever since the launch of 13.10, I have not managed to get past the Network part of the installation on my LiveDVD due to some strange error message that popped up after a short pause that says "**??? ???**" as both the title and the subject. From there, I could not continue nor go back, only Quit the installation.

I even tried this with 12.04 and got the same result.
Here are my old computer's specs: Windows XP (SP3), AMD Athlon Processor, 855MHz, 512MB RAM

Although I have not seen any fixes on the forums and this error is making me lose out on Ubuntu goodness, does anyone know how to fix this error?

Thank you very much,

BlueHattedEngie

Comment: On another note, I think, the computer will struggle to run ubuntu 12.04 or higher.

Answer (score 0):

There are Athlons and then there are Athlons. Specifying which you have is a good idea, for you could have four different versions running at 855MHz.  It could also be *very* useful to discover which network card you have with [lshw](http://ezix.org/project/wiki/HardwareLiSter) while running from the Live disc.

However, standard Ubuntu will run slowly on your machine, and therefore I suggest you consider using the [Lubuntu](http://www.lubuntu.net) or [Xubuntu](http://www.xubuntu.org) variants of Ubuntu as both have a lighter desktop and thereby will run faster, but will run the same apps as stock Ubuntu.